# Background image is cut instead of zooming out

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, bootstrap-5

My website background image responsiveness works during md size -> when it turns in sm and xs it is cut - it means when I want to see the cat during xs I can see only a piece of cat. How to fix it to  see all my background photo during smaller sizes?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?familyans+SC:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <div th:replace="fragments/front_head"></div>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url('img/cattery/main-photo-cut.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: relative; height: 100vh;">
    </div>

<nav th:replace="${@service.getLoggedCustomer()} ? 'fragments/cattery_logged_in_navbar' : 'fragments/cattery_navbar'"></nav>

<footer th:replace="fragments/cattery_footer"></footer>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
padding-top: 120px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the `background-size` and `background-position` css from the style attribute of the .bg-image element. Then try this CSS.

```css
.bg-image{
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .bg-image{
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

The reason it's cropping is the "cover" background size is displaying the entire image centered. Of course that leads to cropping since the smaller sizes are too small to show the whole image in its original size. Contain makes sure you can see all of the image.

Comment: This is a great answer. You can also try `background-size: initial;` to have the img resort to its default size.